# Android camera : Set metering spot position

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm trying to implement tap to focus on a Samsung Xcover4 for an industrial application (specific to this device).
The idea is to have the device stuffed into a kind of box with a hole where the camera is, and to use it to scan cards with qr codes on it.

So the "scan zone" is always the same, and should be set  when the app start with a tap. Once it's done, camera should always focus on that zone and compute exposure on that spot

I'm using Xzing library, so I hacked the CameraManager manager class a little and it's working ok for the fixed focus zone.

I found the "spot" metering value by dumping native camera parameters, but one thing I can't figure out is how to set its position. I guess it can be done, since samsung does it in the native camera app.

```
ArrayList<Camera.Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
focusAreas.add(new Camera.Area(focusArea, 1000));

cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
cameraParameters.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
cameraParameters.setMeteringAreas(focusAreas);
cameraParameters.setZoom(0);
cameraParameters.set("metering", "spot");
camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
camera.autoFocus(autoFocusManager);
```

Below is the list of natvie camera paremeters.

```
3dnr=false;
Infinity=Infinity;
antibanding=50hz;
antibanding-values=auto,50hz;
auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;
auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;
best-capture=0;
brightness=0;
brightness-max=2;
brightness-min=-2;
burst-capture=0;
burstshot-fps-values=(4,4);
constant-growth-rate-zoom-supported=true;
contrast=auto;
drc=false;
dual_mode=-1;
dualrecording-hint=-1;
dynamic-range-control=off;
effect=none;
effect-available-fps-values=(10000,15000);
effect-values=none,mono,negative,sepia,posterize;
effectrecording-hint=0;
exposure-compensation=0;
exposure-compensation-step=0.1;
fast-fps-mode=-1;
flash-mode=off;
flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,torch;
fnumber-value-denominator=10;
fnumber-value-numerator=19;
focal-length=3.70;
focallength-35mm-value=28;
focallength-value-denominator=100;
focallength-value-numerator=370;
focus-areas=(257,416,263,422,1000);
focus-distances=0.10,1.20,Infinity;
focus-mode=auto;
focus-mode-values=auto,macro,continuous-video,continuous-picture;
hdr-mode=0;
horizontal-view-angle=62.2;
hue=0;
hue-max=2;
hue-min=-2;
imageuniqueid-value=V13LLIA02PM V13LLKB16SA
;
intelligent-mode=-1;
iso=auto;
iso-values=auto,100,200,400,800;
jpeg-quality=96;
jpeg-thumbnail-height=384;
jpeg-thumbnail-quality=100;
jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=512x384,512x288,384x384,320x240,0x0;
jpeg-thumbnail-width=512;
max-exposure-compensation=20;
max-num-detected-faces-hw=16;
max-num-detected-faces-sw=0;
max-num-focus-areas=1;
max-num-metering-areas=0;
max-zoom=30;
maxaperture-value-denominator=100;
maxaperture-value-numerator=185;
metering=center;
metering-areas=;
metering-values=matrix,center,spot;
min-exposure-compensation=-20;
odc=false;
phase-af=off;
phase-af-values=off;
picture-format=jpeg;
picture-format-values=jpeg;
picture-size=4128x3096;
picture-size-values=4128x3096,4128x2322,3264x2448,3264x1836,3088x3088,2160x2160,2048x1536,2048x1152,1920x1080,1440x1080,1280x720,960x720,640x480,320x240;
preferred-preview-size-for-video=1280x720;
preview-format=yuv420sp;
preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p;
preview-fps-range=15000,30000;
preview-fps-range-values=(15000,15000),(24000,24000),(15000,30000),(30000,30000);
preview-frame-rate=30;
preview-frame-rate-values=15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30;
preview-size=1280x720;
preview-size-values=1280x720,1056x704,960x720,880x720,720x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;
rotation=0;
rt-hdr=off;
rt-hdr-values=off;
saturation=0;
saturation-max=2;
saturation-min=-2;
scene-mode=auto;
scene-mode-values=auto,action,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,theatre,beach,snow,sunset,steadyphoto,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight;
sharpness=0;
sharpness-max=2;
sharpness-min=-2;
smooth-zoom-supported=false;
vertical-view-angle=39.4;
video-frame-format=nv21;
video-size=1920x1080;
video-size-values=1920x1080,1440x1080,1072x1072,1280x720,960x720,800x450,720x480,640x480,480x320,352x288,320x240,176x144;
video-snapshot-supported=true;
video-stabilization-supported=false;
vrmode=-1;
wdr=0;
whitebalance=auto;
whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight;
zoom=0;
zoom-ratios=100,104,109,114,120,125,131,138,144,151,158,166,174,182,190,200,209,219,229,240,251,263,276,289,303,317,332,348,364,381,400;
zoom-supported=true
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm RE-ing the Samsung camera right now and you might be able to call CameraContext.updateTouchAEPosition(int, int, bool). If that does not work, you might be force to lock AE/AF and simulate a touch, listen to onActivityTouchEvent, lock controls when touch event is received. Hope this helps, they're just suppositions.

Comment: @brainwash I ended up using Camera2 API with google vision for barcode detection. I superclassed the barcode detector to rezise frames before doing the actual detection, in order to limit the detection area. Thanks anyway, your solution would have probably been the way to go with Camera1 API.